# Api to get web application development technologies

Tags: web-applications, webtrends

I am developing an application which notifies the users about new technology solutions in web application development. Is there any api available to get new technology solutions in web application development from stackoverflow or similar websites? like https://hotframeworks.com or https://db-engines.com/en/ranking

Comment: Questions asking for libraries, tools, api,... recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Can you please recommend a place to ask this question?